# For Loop with txt file

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to perform a set of actions for each website I have saved in the txt file "webpages.txt" I am not the most familiar with python, but in powershell I would normally use a "foreach variable in txt do this" kind of script. How would this be achieved through python?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
with open ("C:\Users\Desktop\Notes\Scripts\Download_PDF\webpages.txt") as sheet:
    for websites in sheet:
        browser.visit('websites')
        browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/ul/li[4]').click()
        browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```

Python reads 'websites' not as a string, not a variable. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: `browser.visit(websites)` without the quotes.

Comment: be careful with literal windows path, use raw string prefix: `r"C:\Users\Desktop\Notes\Scripts\Download_PDF\webpages.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.visit('websites')
```

is passing the string 'websites'. To use the variable just pass:

```
browser.visit(websites)
```

it is also better to rename `websites` to `website` - as each line in the file is a single website (i assume).